# Will the fastboot boot ramdisk command boot a coreboot ramdisk to boot from usb/ sd card without mods?

Tags: recovery-mode, usb, external-sd, custom-roms, ram

Of course it has to be signed and not exceed a size-limit, but I think that custom roms or os's should come to a bigger audience without the limiting security and guarantee risks, disabling the ability to update for example.

I like coreboot because it can boot anything.

I hope one day a coreboot ramdisk would available for various snapdragon devices.

Then the playload can detect the usb/ sd card and fire the os.

Would this be possible?

**Edit:** Ofc not on Samsung, not even utilizing the fastboot mode.